# Performing an Update query with a date

Tags: sql

Can I perform an update query by checking the value of the date whether the date entered is greater than the date stored in the database.

```
IF @input_date > table.date
  UPDATE table SET table.value = 0, table.date = @input_date
ELSE 
  UPDATE table SET table.value = @input_value, table.date = @input_date
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use **[CASE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181765.aspx)** Statement

Try this

```
    UPDATE table 
    SET table.value = CASE WHEN @input_date > table.date THEN 0 ELSE @input_value END,
        table.date = @input_date
```

Comment: Of course! Using a Case statement. I will try that and will update with results, thank you.

Comment: Thanks! I need to keep practicing to remember these basics.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to do this would be putting the test into the where condition of the update statement. So that the update only happens when the condition is met

```
update
    table
set
    table.value = @input_date
where
    table.value < @input_date
```